# Overriding navigation movement error for PictureScrollField

Tags: blackberry, navigation, scroll

I'm trying to over-ride `protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx,int dy,int status,int time)` in a `MainScreen` subclass and I have a `PictureScrollField` added to it. If I do not over-ride it, then the `PictureScrollField` works normally but when I do over-ride it, then the `currentImageIndex` stays fixed at zero and it doesn't scroll! What can I do to prevent this anomaly or is there another (better) way to do this? I just want to change the title of a field with the current image of `PictureScrollField`. In other words, I need to get the `currentImageIndex` for dynamically changing the data visible on the screen. The Field is a custom one so I could not use label/callout features for a `ScrollEntry`.

EDIT: I'm over-riding `protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx,int dy,int status,int time)` and returning `false` but that wasn't working.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand; Tell me briefly;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to work around the default behaviour of `PictureScrollField` as follows:

```
protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx,int dy,int status,int time){
// gallery is an object of PictureScrollField
    if(gallery.getVisualState()==Field.VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS && dx != 0){
        int currentInd = gallery.getCurrentImageIndex() + dx;
        gallery.selectImageAtCoordinate((dx)*50 + Display.getWidth()/2);
        // 50 is the width of the gallery object as provided in the constructor
        // Instead of 50, we can also write gallery.getWidth()
        // use the current image index as - gallery.getCurrentImageIndex()
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's weird, though, that despite returning `false` (which means that the event was not consumed), `PictureScrollField` wasn't handling the navigation movements! Anyway, manually setting the `currentImageIndex` works equally well!